# Azure APIM Developer Portal - Authorization flow console errors

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

When trying to use `Authorization` in the Developer Portal, I keep receiving an error. The popup opens, the login works, the popup closes and no token is sent back due to an error. It worked without Custom Domain. I added Custom Domains for "Portal, Management and Gateway".

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://apim-xxx.developer.azure-api.net') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://dev.xxx.custom.com').

[image]

In the call back page, I can see the developer portal puts the default URL and not the Custom Domain:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by Azure Front Door, not correctly setting the 'Backend host header' causing APIM to use the wrong (original) domain.

Also another tip for those who run into issues with Front Door. Turn caching off in front door and republish the APIM Developer Portal after every Oauth / domain change.